# is this better design with use Angular2 with TIBCO rest and EMS?

Tags: database, spring, rest, angular, tibco

I have group of people to enforce a design structure to use angular2 app as separate and rest of everything will be take care by TIBCO rest, EMS, Database.
My doubt is that :
Is this correct approach?
I am suggesting to use Angular2+spring+database and this combination will trigger a specific EMS job which needs to be done and this EMS is already in place.
Current TIBCO code is so massy and hard to manage and with new approach it can go in proper design way as it should be. 
Please help me with your inputs with merits and demerits of Angular2 + TIBCO (no java at all)? Please consider maintainability, penetration, release, versioning of the changes(Team doesn't manage TIBCO EMS versioning).
Thanks in advance..